# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position

Tags: python

```
def read():
    numbers = []
    with open("C:\Users\coder\Documents\Programacion\python_intermedio\clase_ambiente\numbers.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
            numbers.append(int(line))
    print(numbers)

def run():
    write()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

> File "C:\Users\coder\Documents\Programacion\python_intermedio\clase_ambiente\archivos.py", line 3
> with open("C:\Users\coder\Documents\Programacion\python_intermedio\clase_ambiente\numbers.txt", "r") as f:
> consigo
> ^
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 3):

Un error lo tienes en:

```
with open("C:\Users\coder\Documents ... ", "r") as f:
```

Se debe a que las barras invertidas son [caracteres de escape](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html) en casi todos los lenguajes de programación y es justamente lo que usa Windows para sus rutas de archivos. Se puede resolver escapando las propias barras, poniendo doble barras `\\`,

```
"C:\\Users\\coder\\Documents\\...etc"
```

Otra forma también puede ser usando [el prefijo](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) `r` en la cadena:

```
r"C:\Users\coder\Documents\...etc"
```

También funciona usando el estilo Unix:

```
"C:/Users/coder/Documents/...etc"
```

Comment: En concreto, `\U` es la secuencia de escape para _[code points](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point)_ Unicode, por lo que intenta interpretar como el hexadecimal del code point lo que encuentra : `\Users`. Lo comento porque, si bien tu respuesta da una posible solución, no explica el mensaje de error que está encontrando el AP.

Comment: Solucionado!
Muchas gracias